# crypt module not outputting a SHA512 hash as expected

Tags: python, security, hash, sha, crypt

I'm currently using the crypt module in Python to try and create a SHA512 hash in the following manner.

When I run the following line of code from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463285/7489488):

```
>>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt('password', '$6$' + 'salt1234')
```

Instead of seeing the following output of the salt followed by the SHA512 hash per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463285/7489488):

```
'$6$salt1234$Zr07alHmuONZlfKILiGKKULQZaBG6Qmf5smHCNH35KnciTapZ7dItwaCv5SKZ1xH9ydG59SCgkdtsTqVWGhk81'
```

I get the following:

```
$6FMi11BJFsAc
```

Below is a screenshot as proof:

[image]

Why is it that I'm unable to obtain the SHA512 hash that I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html:

> This module implements an interface to the *crypt(3)* routine, which is a one-way hash function based upon a modified DES algorithm; see the Unix man page for further details. […]
>
> Notice that the behavior of this module depends on the actual implementation of the *crypt(3)* routine in the running system. Therefore, any extensions available on the current implementation will also be available on this module.

and [from the documentation of the function itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html#crypt.crypt) (emphasis mine):

> The optional salt is either a string as returned from `mksalt()`, one of the `crypt.METHOD_*` values (**though not all may be available on all platforms**)

The `crypt` of the platform you’re on probably doesn’t support SHA-512. You can confirm this by checking whether `crypt.METHOD_SHA512` is in `crypt.methods`.

```
>>> crypt.methods
[<crypt.METHOD_CRYPT>]
>>> "\N{CRYING FACE}"
''
```

One could look at [a description of SHAcrypt](https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) and make an implementation based on it, or [use someone else’s](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.sha512_crypt.html).

```
from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt
sha512_crypt.hash('password')
```